# i am very confused about reading from txt file

Tags: c

sorry i'm new at c
i want to read these data from txt file.

```
A 7
c 5
y 6
U 9
j 4
Z 3
z 5
0
```

here is my code

```
 while(feof(input)==0){
    char c;
    int num;
    fscanf(input,"%c%d",&c,&num);
    printf("%c:%d\n",c,num);
}
```

but result in console is not same as txt file
the result is

Open file complete

```
A:7

:7
c:5

:5
y:6

:6
U:9

:9
j:4

:4
Z:3

:3
z:5

:0
```

my code is correct, isn't it?

Answer (score 8):

> ```
> fscanf(input,"%c%d",&c,&num);
> ```
>
> my code is correct, isn't it

You're not eating the newlines. Change that to:

```
fscanf(input,"%c%d ",&c,&num);
                  ^
```

As explanation, each line ends with a a character, `'\n'`. If you don't do anything about it, `%c` will try to read it and you'll get confusing results. A cheap trick is to add a blank space in `fscanf` which makes it eat all blanks after a `%c%d` couple.

#### EDIT

In light of comment from  Peter Kowalski:

> shouldn't it be fscanf(input,"%c %d ",&c,&num); ? I've put additional
>   space between %c and %d

This is a very good question. Thing is `%d` is one of the specifiers that **ignore leading space**. No matter how many blanks are in the stream, `scanf` will eat and discard them. Therefore a blank before `%d` is implicit.

Comment: This is a better solution than mine in that it fixes the problem at the source. Still need to replace the `:` with a blank space in the `printf()`

Comment: @aratn0n The "thank you mechanism" :-) on SO consists of "upvoting" (click the up-triangle) *any number* of answers that were helpful. If *one* in particular was best for you, then you can [accept it by clicking the checkmark](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) next to the answer. This rewards both parties with some points and marks the problem as solved.

Comment: @cnicutar I have a question - shouldn't it be `fscanf(input,"%c %d ",&c,&num);` ? I've put additional space between `%c` and `%d` That way it omits the space between input, doesn't it?

Comment: @PeterKowalski I edited the answer to address your comment :-)

Answer (score 5):

You also need to eat the newlines.

```
fscanf(input,"%c%d\n",&c,&num);
```

Answer (score 2):

Quick fix: simply adjust your `printf()` statement from

```
 printf("%c:%d\n",c,num);
```

to

```
 printf("%c %d",c,num);
```

There are other ways, like adjusting your current `scanf()`, which is better as it fixes the problem at the source (you are reading and keeping the newline).

Alternatively you could just read the whole line without parsing it into components and print it out.